# Remove the default login/register page for visitors in PHPFox and redirect visitors to a particular page

Tags: redirect, phpfox

I'd like visitors (unregistered users) to be redirected to a particular page, say, blogs or pages for my phpfox site (i.e they are able to see content which is shared with everyone).

Currently, when a visitor comes to my phpfox site, e.g. `www.mysite.com`, the user sees the login/register forms, which I want to do away with. I want the visitor to be redirected to, say, `http://mysite.com/index.php?do=/pages/`
or 
`http://mysite.com/index.php?do=/`

Which particular files should I be looking at?

Answer (score 0):

In order to navigate visitors to the other page you can use default function of phpfox to redirect page use send function of URL lib (`Phpfox::getLib('url')->send('pin');`).

Here in the above code i have coded to navigate the page  to the pin module you can use the code to redirect your page to a particular destination.

Use the code on the top line of process function of the index-visitor.class file 'module\core\include\component\controller\index-visitor.class'